# Hadoop user on Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: linux, hadoop, apt, debian-jessie

I've an error when i try to launch Synaptic Package Manager.

I've installed Hadoop single cluster following this guide

https://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-single-node-cluster-on-centos-redhat/

and also this

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

I login to Debian 8 with as a defaultuser, click on APT and window ask me the hadoopuser password.

If i switch Debian user (hadoopuser) and try to click on APT the window ask me the same password for hadoopuser again.

Defaultuser has a group, hadoopuser has another group.

Why APT don't ask me the password for the user that i'm using?

NB: when i login into Debian i've 2 user: defaultuser and hadoopuser. This work fine.

Comment: Can you pleae explain what is connection between Synaptic Package Manager and Hadoop ?

You didn't use packages to install hadoop so it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: To create hadoop service i've created a dedicated user, but now, when i try to launch APT the window ask me hadoopuser password, not the current user password. I've installed Hadoop with the guide in the link above.

Comment: NB: hadoop works fine. it's under /usr/local/hadoop

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/sudoers i've connected hadoopuser with "sudo" group. this was the problem...